# How can i connect to wlan with my BCM4313 (14e4:4727)?

Tags: wireless, networking, drivers, broadcom

i am looking for help for getting my Broadcom Wlan card working on my laptop with Ubuntu.
Until now i was not able to get it to work.
Solutions i tried for now:
  1. using the additional driver that can be installed via the ubuntu additional driver menu
  2. using ndiswrapper with the appropriate Windows XP driver for the BCM4313

Both solutions seem to have the same problems. You can scan for available wlans (iwlist scan).
Also wlan frontends from ubtuntu and kubuntu can find wlans. But connecting to them is not successful. 
Finally i did my tests using the wicd-client frontend.

Question:
How can i fix the problem so i can connect to the network? How can i see what is going wrong?

My Hardware:

### > lspci -vnn  | grep 14e4

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:4727] (rev 01)



uname -r
3.13.0-24-generic
```

## First test using ndiswrapper:

Windows XP driver:
   h20565.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/psi/swdDetails/?cc=us&lang=en&sp4ts.oid=3688870&swItem=ob_101092_1&ac.admitted=1399152253163.876444892.492883150

### > dmesg

```
[   30.871555] ndiswrapper: module verification failed: signature and/or  required key missing - tainting kernel
[   30.871610] Disabling lock debugging due to kernel taint
[   30.874973] ndiswrapper version 1.59 loaded (smp=yes, preempt=no)
[   31.470169] usbcore: registered new interface driver ndiswrapper
[  405.925514] usbcore: deregistering interface driver ndiswrapper
[  405.949538] ndiswrapper version 1.59 loaded (smp=yes, preempt=no)
[  405.980682] ndiswrapper: driver bcmwl5 (Broadcom,03/22/2010, 5.60.350.6) loaded
[  405.997568] ndiswrapper: using IRQ 17
[  406.260345] wlan0: ethernet device 7c:e9:d3:12:2b:e6 using NDIS driver: bcmwl5, version: 0x53c15e0, NDIS version: 0x501, vendor: 'NDIS Network Adapter', 14E4:4727.5.conf
[  406.263500] wlan0: encryption modes supported: WEP; TKIP with WPA, WPA2, WPA2-PSK; AES/CCMP with WPA, WPA2, WPA2-PSK
[  406.264752] usbcore: registered new interface driver ndiswrapper
[  406.308733] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
```

### > /var/log/syslog

```
May  3 20:28:01 bell NetworkManager[1301]: <info> Unmanaged Device found; state CONNECTED forced. (see http://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/191889)
May  3 20:28:27 bell dhclient: Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.2.4
May  3 20:28:27 bell dhclient: Copyright 2004-2012 Internet Systems Consortium.
May  3 20:28:27 bell dhclient: All rights reserved.
May  3 20:28:27 bell dhclient: For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
May  3 20:28:27 bell dhclient: 
May  3 20:28:27 bell dhclient: Listening on LPF/wlan0/7c:e9:d3:12:2b:e6
May  3 20:28:27 bell dhclient: Sending on   LPF/wlan0/7c:e9:d3:12:2b:e6
May  3 20:28:27 bell dhclient: Sending on   Socket/fallback
May  3 20:28:27 bell NetworkManager[1301]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: inactive -> disabled
May  3 20:28:27 bell kernel: [ 1869.577168] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
May  3 20:28:27 bell NetworkManager[1301]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: disabled -> scanning
May  3 20:28:27 bell wpa_supplicant[4144]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-TERMINATING 
May  3 20:28:27 bell NetworkManager[1301]: <info> wpa_supplicant stopped
May  3 20:28:27 bell NetworkManager[1301]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> down
May  3 20:28:27 bell NetworkManager[1301]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: disconnected -> unavailable (reason 'supplicant-failed') [30 20 10]
May  3 20:28:27 bell NetworkManager[1301]: <info> (wlan0): deactivating device (reason 'supplicant-failed') [10]
May  3 20:28:27 bell dbus[556]: [system] Activating service name='fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1' (using servicehelper)
May  3 20:28:27 bell NetworkManager[1301]: <info> Unmanaged Device found; state CONNECTED forced. (see http://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/191889)
May  3 20:28:27 bell dbus[556]: [system] Successfully activated service 'fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1'
May  3 20:28:27 bell NetworkManager[1301]: <info> wpa_supplicant started
May  3 20:28:28 bell wpa_supplicant[4930]: Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
May  3 20:28:28 bell wpa_supplicant[4937]: nl80211: 'nl80211' generic netlink not found
May  3 20:28:28 bell wpa_supplicant[4937]: Failed to initialize driver 'nl80211'
May  3 20:28:28 bell kernel: [ 1869.701065] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
May  3 20:28:28 bell dhclient: Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.2.4
May  3 20:28:28 bell dhclient: Copyright 2004-2012 Internet Systems Consortium.
May  3 20:28:28 bell dhclient: All rights reserved.
May  3 20:28:28 bell dhclient: For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
May  3 20:28:28 bell dhclient: 
May  3 20:28:28 bell dhclient: Listening on LPF/p2p1/04:7d:7b:21:3f:cd
May  3 20:28:28 bell dhclient: Sending on   LPF/p2p1/04:7d:7b:21:3f:cd
May  3 20:28:28 bell dhclient: Sending on   Socket/fallback
May  3 20:28:28 bell NetworkManager[1301]: <info> (wlan0) supports 1 scan SSIDs
May  3 20:28:28 bell NetworkManager[1301]: <warn> Trying to remove a non-existant call id.
May  3 20:28:28 bell NetworkManager[1301]: <info> (wlan0) supports 1 scan SSIDs
May  3 20:28:28 bell NetworkManager[1301]: <info> (wlan0) supports 1 scan SSIDs
May  3 20:28:28 bell NetworkManager[1301]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: starting -> ready
May  3 20:28:28 bell NetworkManager[1301]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'supplicant-available') [20 30 42]
May  3 20:28:28 bell NetworkManager[1301]: <info> Unmanaged Device found; state CONNECTED forced. (see http://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/191889)
May  3 20:28:28 bell NetworkManager[1301]: <warn> Trying to remove a non-existant call id.
May  3 20:28:28 bell wpa_supplicant[4937]: wlan0: Reject scan trigger since one is already pending
May  3 20:28:28 bell NetworkManager[1301]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: ready -> disconnected
May  3 20:28:28 bell NetworkManager[1301]: <info> (wlan0) supports 1 scan SSIDs
May  3 20:28:28 bell dhclient: DHCPRELEASE on p2p1 to 192.168.0.1 port 67 (xid=0x20941599)
May  3 20:28:28 bell avahi-daemon[651]: Withdrawing address record for 192.168.0.45 on p2p1.
May  3 20:28:28 bell avahi-daemon[651]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface p2p1.IPv4 with address 192.168.0.45.
May  3 20:28:28 bell avahi-daemon[651]: Interface p2p1.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
May  3 20:28:28 bell avahi-daemon[651]: Interface p2p1.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
May  3 20:28:28 bell avahi-daemon[651]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface p2p1.IPv6 with address fe80::67d:7bff:fe21:3fcd.
May  3 20:28:28 bell avahi-daemon[651]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::67d:7bff:fe21:3fcd on p2p1.
May  3 20:28:28 bell kernel: [ 1870.194760] r8169 0000:01:00.0 p2p1: link down
May  3 20:28:28 bell kernel: [ 1870.194818] r8169 0000:01:00.0 p2p1: link down
May  3 20:28:28 bell kernel: [ 1870.194907] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): p2p1: link is not ready
May  3 20:28:28 bell NetworkManager[1301]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> disabled
May  3 20:28:28 bell dhclient: Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.2.4
May  3 20:28:28 bell dhclient: Copyright 2004-2012 Internet Systems Consortium.
May  3 20:28:28 bell dhclient: All rights reserved.
May  3 20:28:28 bell dhclient: For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
May  3 20:28:28 bell dhclient: 
May  3 20:28:28 bell dhclient: Listening on LPF/wlan0/7c:e9:d3:12:2b:e6
May  3 20:28:28 bell dhclient: Sending on   LPF/wlan0/7c:e9:d3:12:2b:e6
May  3 20:28:28 bell dhclient: Sending on   Socket/fallback
May  3 20:28:28 bell kernel: [ 1870.439315] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
May  3 20:28:28 bell wpa_supplicant[4937]: wlan0: Reject scan trigger since one is already pending
May  3 20:28:28 bell wpa_supplicant[4937]: wlan0: Failed to initiate AP scan
May  3 20:28:28 bell wpa_supplicant[4937]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-TERMINATING 
May  3 20:28:28 bell NetworkManager[1301]: <info> wpa_supplicant stopped
May  3 20:28:28 bell NetworkManager[1301]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: disabled -> down
May  3 20:28:28 bell NetworkManager[1301]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: disconnected -> unavailable (reason 'supplicant-failed') [30 20 10]
May  3 20:28:28 bell NetworkManager[1301]: <info> (wlan0): deactivating device (reason 'supplicant-failed') [10]
May  3 20:28:28 bell dbus[556]: [system] Activating service name='fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1' (using servicehelper)
May  3 20:28:28 bell NetworkManager[1301]: <info> Unmanaged Device found; state CONNECTED forced. (see http://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/191889)
May  3 20:28:28 bell kernel: [ 1870.498360] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
May  3 20:28:28 bell dbus[556]: [system] Successfully activated service 'fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1'
May  3 20:28:28 bell NetworkManager[1301]: <info> wpa_supplicant started
May  3 20:28:28 bell wpa_supplicant[5005]: Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
May  3 20:28:28 bell wpa_supplicant[5006]: nl80211: 'nl80211' generic netlink not found
May  3 20:28:28 bell wpa_supplicant[5006]: Failed to initialize driver 'nl80211'
May  3 20:28:28 bell NetworkManager[1301]: <info> (wlan0) supports 1 scan SSIDs
May  3 20:28:28 bell NetworkManager[1301]: <warn> Trying to remove a non-existant call id.
May  3 20:28:28 bell NetworkManager[1301]: <info> (wlan0) supports 1 scan SSIDs
May  3 20:28:28 bell NetworkManager[1301]: <info> (wlan0) supports 1 scan SSIDs
May  3 20:28:28 bell NetworkManager[1301]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: starting -> ready
May  3 20:28:28 bell NetworkManager[1301]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'supplicant-available') [20 30 42]
May  3 20:28:28 bell NetworkManager[1301]: <info> Unmanaged Device found; state CONNECTED forced. (see http://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/191889)
May  3 20:28:28 bell NetworkManager[1301]: <warn> Trying to remove a non-existant call id.
May  3 20:28:28 bell NetworkManager[1301]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: ready -> disconnected
May  3 20:28:28 bell NetworkManager[1301]: <info> (wlan0) supports 1 scan SSIDs
May  3 20:28:28 bell wpa_supplicant[5006]: wlan0: Reject scan trigger since one is already pending
May  3 20:28:30 bell kernel: [ 1871.782264] r8169 0000:01:00.0 p2p1: link up
May  3 20:28:30 bell kernel: [ 1871.782306] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): p2p1: link becomes ready
May  3 20:28:31 bell NetworkManager[1301]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> disabled
May  3 20:28:31 bell avahi-daemon[651]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface p2p1.IPv6 with address fe80::67d:7bff:fe21:3fcd.
May  3 20:28:31 bell avahi-daemon[651]: New relevant interface p2p1.IPv6 for mDNS.
May  3 20:28:31 bell avahi-daemon[651]: Registering new address record for fe80::67d:7bff:fe21:3fcd on p2p1.*.
May  3 20:28:38 bell NetworkManager[1301]: <info> wpa_supplicant die count reset
May  3 20:29:06 bell dhclient: Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.2.4
May  3 20:29:06 bell dhclient: Copyright 2004-2012 Internet Systems Consortium.
May  3 20:29:06 bell dhclient: All rights reserved.
May  3 20:29:06 bell dhclient: For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
May  3 20:29:06 bell dhclient: 
May  3 20:29:06 bell dhclient: Listening on LPF/wlan0/7c:e9:d3:12:2b:e6
May  3 20:29:06 bell dhclient: Sending on   LPF/wlan0/7c:e9:d3:12:2b:e6
May  3 20:29:06 bell dhclient: Sending on   Socket/fallback
May  3 20:29:06 bell kernel: [ 1908.514481] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
May  3 20:29:06 bell kernel: [ 1908.546806] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
May  3 20:29:06 bell wpa_supplicant[5006]: message repeated 2 times: [ wlan0: Reject scan trigger since one is already pending]
May  3 20:29:06 bell wpa_supplicant[5006]: wlan0: Failed to initiate AP scan
May  3 20:29:06 bell NetworkManager[1301]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: disabled -> disconnected
May  3 20:29:06 bell wpa_supplicant[5006]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-TERMINATING 
May  3 20:29:06 bell NetworkManager[1301]: <info> wpa_supplicant stopped
May  3 20:29:06 bell NetworkManager[1301]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> down
May  3 20:29:06 bell NetworkManager[1301]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: disconnected -> unavailable (reason 'supplicant-failed') [30 20 10]
May  3 20:29:06 bell NetworkManager[1301]: <info> (wlan0): deactivating device (reason 'supplicant-failed') [10]
May  3 20:29:06 bell dbus[556]: [system] Activating service name='fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1' (using servicehelper)
May  3 20:29:06 bell NetworkManager[1301]: <info> Unmanaged Device found; state CONNECTED forced. (see http://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/191889)
May  3 20:29:06 bell dbus[556]: [system] Successfully activated service 'fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1'
May  3 20:29:06 bell NetworkManager[1301]: <info> wpa_supplicant started
May  3 20:29:06 bell dhclient: Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.2.4
May  3 20:29:06 bell dhclient: Copyright 2004-2012 Internet Systems Consortium.
May  3 20:29:06 bell dhclient: All rights reserved.
May  3 20:29:06 bell dhclient: For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
May  3 20:29:06 bell dhclient: 
May  3 20:29:06 bell wpa_supplicant[5098]: Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
May  3 20:29:06 bell wpa_supplicant[5100]: nl80211: 'nl80211' generic netlink not found
May  3 20:29:06 bell wpa_supplicant[5100]: Failed to initialize driver 'nl80211'
May  3 20:29:07 bell kernel: [ 1908.710778] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
May  3 20:29:07 bell dhclient: Listening on LPF/p2p1/04:7d:7b:21:3f:cd
May  3 20:29:07 bell dhclient: Sending on   LPF/p2p1/04:7d:7b:21:3f:cd
May  3 20:29:07 bell dhclient: Sending on   Socket/fallback
May  3 20:29:07 bell NetworkManager[1301]: <info> (wlan0) supports 1 scan SSIDs
May  3 20:29:07 bell NetworkManager[1301]: <warn> Trying to remove a non-existant call id.
May  3 20:29:07 bell dhclient: DHCPRELEASE on p2p1 to 192.168.0.1 port 67 (xid=0x1aaf8d08)
May  3 20:29:07 bell dhclient: send_packet: Network is unreachable
May  3 20:29:07 bell dhclient: send_packet: please consult README file regarding broadcast address.
May  3 20:29:07 bell dhclient: dhclient.c:2365: Failed to send 300 byte long packet over fallback interface.
May  3 20:29:07 bell NetworkManager[1301]: <info> (wlan0) supports 1 scan SSIDs
May  3 20:29:07 bell NetworkManager[1301]: <info> (wlan0) supports 1 scan SSIDs
May  3 20:29:07 bell NetworkManager[1301]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: starting -> ready
May  3 20:29:07 bell NetworkManager[1301]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'supplicant-available') [20 30 42]
May  3 20:29:07 bell NetworkManager[1301]: <info> Unmanaged Device found; state CONNECTED forced. (see http://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/191889)
May  3 20:29:07 bell NetworkManager[1301]: <warn> Trying to remove a non-existant call id.
May  3 20:29:07 bell wpa_supplicant[5100]: wlan0: Reject scan trigger since one is already pending
May  3 20:29:07 bell NetworkManager[1301]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: ready -> disconnected
May  3 20:29:07 bell NetworkManager[1301]: <info> (wlan0) supports 1 scan SSIDs
May  3 20:29:07 bell avahi-daemon[651]: Interface p2p1.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
May  3 20:29:07 bell avahi-daemon[651]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface p2p1.IPv6 with address fe80::67d:7bff:fe21:3fcd.
May  3 20:29:07 bell avahi-daemon[651]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::67d:7bff:fe21:3fcd on p2p1.
May  3 20:29:07 bell kernel: [ 1909.094908] r8169 0000:01:00.0 p2p1: link down
May  3 20:29:07 bell kernel: [ 1909.094953] r8169 0000:01:00.0 p2p1: link down
May  3 20:29:07 bell kernel: [ 1909.095303] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): p2p1: link is not ready
May  3 20:29:08 bell kernel: [ 1910.650767] r8169 0000:01:00.0 p2p1: link up
May  3 20:29:08 bell kernel: [ 1910.650808] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): p2p1: link becomes ready
May  3 20:29:10 bell avahi-daemon[651]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface p2p1.IPv6 with address fe80::67d:7bff:fe21:3fcd.
May  3 20:29:10 bell avahi-daemon[651]: New relevant interface p2p1.IPv6 for mDNS.
May  3 20:29:10 bell avahi-daemon[651]: Registering new address record for fe80::67d:7bff:fe21:3fcd on p2p1.*.
May  3 20:29:17 bell NetworkManager[1301]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> inactive
May  3 20:29:17 bell NetworkManager[1301]: <info> wpa_supplicant die count reset
May  3 20:34:05 bell dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on p2p1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x1ce727d7)
May  3 20:34:06 bell dhclient: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.0.45 on p2p1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x1ce727d7)
May  3 20:34:06 bell dhclient: DHCPOFFER of 192.168.0.45 from 192.168.0.1
May  3 20:34:06 bell dhclient: DHCPACK of 192.168.0.45 from 192.168.0.1
May  3 20:34:06 bell avahi-daemon[651]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface p2p1.IPv4 with address 192.168.0.45.
May  3 20:34:06 bell avahi-daemon[651]: New relevant interface p2p1.IPv4 for mDNS.
May  3 20:34:06 bell avahi-daemon[651]: Registering new address record for 192.168.0.45 on p2p1.IPv4.
May  3 20:34:08 bell dhclient: bound to 192.168.0.45 -- renewal in 339626 seconds.
May  3 20:36:41 bell rtkit-daemon[1789]: Successfully made thread 5527 of process 5527 (n/a) owned by '1000' high priority at nice level -11.
May  3 20:36:41 bell rtkit-daemon[1789]: Supervising 1 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
May  3 20:36:41 bell rtkit-daemon[1789]: Successfully made thread 5528 of process 5527 (n/a) owned by '1000' RT at priority 5.
May  3 20:36:41 bell rtkit-daemon[1789]: Supervising 2 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
May  3 20:36:41 bell rtkit-daemon[1789]: Successfully made thread 5529 of process 5527 (n/a) owned by '1000' RT at priority 5.
```

## My second test was using the external  driver (closed source, STA?):

### > lsmod | grep wl

```
wl                   3999690  0 
lib80211               14040  2 wl,lib80211_crypt_tkip
cfg80211              409394  1 wl
```

### > modinfo wl

```
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-24-generic/updates/dkms/wl.ko
license:        MIXED/Proprietary
srcversion:     FF25FE784DC6BDFF69DAFCB
alias:          pci:v*d*sv*sd*bc02sc80i*
depends:        cfg80211,lib80211
vermagic:       3.13.0-24-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 686 
parm:           wl_txq_thresh:int
parm:           oneonly:int
parm:           piomode:int
parm:           instance_base:int
parm:           nompc:int
parm:           intf_name:string
```

### > dmesg

```
[  348.676644] systemd-hostnamed[3372]: Warning: nss-myhostname is not installed. Changing the local hostname might make it unresolveable. Please install nss-myhostname!
[  391.527312] perf samples too long (2518 > 2500), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 50000
[  517.280745] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[  517.293755] lib80211: common routines for IEEE802.11 drivers
[  517.293764] lib80211_crypt: registered algorithm 'NULL'
[  517.352703] INFO @wl_cfg80211_attach : Registered CFG80211 phy
[  517.372861] lib80211_crypt: registered algorithm 'TKIP'
[  517.510968] wlan0: Broadcom BCM4727 802.11 Hybrid Wireless Controller 6.30.223.141 (r415941)
[  518.733753] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[  518.733767] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
[  518.733774] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[  518.733779] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[  518.733784] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[  518.733789] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[  518.733795] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
```

### > less /var/log/syslog

http://pastebin.com/9M0PwLWq (limit exceeded here)

### > less /var/log/wicd/wicd.log

```
2014/05/03 22:12:32 :: Connecting to wireless network FritzOA
2014/05/03 22:12:32 :: attempting to set hostname with dhclient
2014/05/03 22:12:32 :: using dhcpcd or another supported client may work better
2014/05/03 22:12:32 :: attempting to set hostname with dhclient
2014/05/03 22:12:32 :: using dhcpcd or another supported client may work better
2014/05/03 22:12:33 :: Putting interface down
2014/05/03 22:12:33 :: Releasing DHCP leases...
2014/05/03 22:12:33 :: attempting to set hostname with dhclient
2014/05/03 22:12:33 :: using dhcpcd or another supported client may work better
2014/05/03 22:12:33 :: Setting false IP...
2014/05/03 22:12:33 :: Stopping wpa_supplicant
2014/05/03 22:12:33 :: Flushing the routing table...
2014/05/03 22:12:33 :: Putting interface up...
2014/05/03 22:12:35 :: Generating psk...
2014/05/03 22:12:35 :: Attempting to authenticate...
2014/05/03 22:13:11 :: wpa_supplicant authentication may have failed.
2014/05/03 22:13:11 :: connect result is failed
2014/05/03 22:13:11 :: exiting connection thread
2014/05/03 22:13:11 :: Sending connection attempt result bad_pass
2014/05/03 22:13:11 :: attempting to set hostname with dhclient
2014/05/03 22:13:11 :: using dhcpcd or another supported client may work better
2014/05/03 22:13:12 :: attempting to set hostname with dhclient
2014/05/03 22:13:12 :: using dhcpcd or another supported client may work better
```

## connect unencrypted / unsecured accesspoint, Android tethering hotspot

### >less /var/log/syslog

http://pastebin.com/MHDYf51w (too big)

### > less /var/log/wicd/wicd.log

```
2014/05/03 22:22:32 :: Connecting to wireless network AndroidAP
2014/05/03 22:22:32 :: attempting to set hostname with dhclient
2014/05/03 22:22:32 :: using dhcpcd or another supported client may work better
2014/05/03 22:22:32 :: attempting to set hostname with dhclient
2014/05/03 22:22:32 :: using dhcpcd or another supported client may work better
2014/05/03 22:22:33 :: Putting interface down
2014/05/03 22:22:33 :: Releasing DHCP leases...
2014/05/03 22:22:33 :: attempting to set hostname with dhclient
2014/05/03 22:22:33 :: using dhcpcd or another supported client may work better
2014/05/03 22:22:33 :: Setting false IP...
2014/05/03 22:22:33 :: Stopping wpa_supplicant
2014/05/03 22:22:33 :: Flushing the routing table...
2014/05/03 22:22:33 :: Putting interface up...
2014/05/03 22:22:35 :: Running DHCP with hostname bell
2014/05/03 22:22:35 :: attempting to set hostname with dhclient
2014/05/03 22:22:35 :: using dhcpcd or another supported client may work better
2014/05/03 22:22:35 :: Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.2.4
2014/05/03 22:22:35 :: Copyright 2004-2012 Internet Systems Consortium.
2014/05/03 22:22:35 :: All rights reserved.
2014/05/03 22:22:35 :: For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
2014/05/03 22:22:35 :: 
2014/05/03 22:22:35 :: Listening on LPF/wlan0/7c:e9:d3:12:2b:e6
2014/05/03 22:22:35 :: Sending on   LPF/wlan0/7c:e9:d3:12:2b:e6
2014/05/03 22:22:35 :: Sending on   Socket/fallback
2014/05/03 22:22:35 :: DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x4b6721af)
2014/05/03 22:22:38 :: DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 4 (xid=0x4b6721af)
2014/05/03 22:22:42 :: DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 8 (xid=0x4b6721af)
2014/05/03 22:22:50 :: DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 13 (xid=0x4b6721af)
2014/05/03 22:23:03 :: DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 19 (xid=0x4b6721af)
2014/05/03 22:23:22 :: DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 19 (xid=0x4b6721af)
```

Comment: For Device "14e4:4727" under Ubuntu 14.04 LTS it is said there:   

"... Special Case #1 - This device uses the driver combination bcma and brcmsmac. It shouldn't be necessary to install anything at all. Required firmware is installed by default in the package linux-firmware. ..."

This i can confirm, the wireless card was listed and wireless networks shown up.
But i could not connect to any network. That makes me think the list is not complete?
I will try the approach from "Jim Rogers" on the comments and will let you know, thanks.

Comment: Hi, i reinstalled the system, and wow, i could connect to wlan. There was one thing i did differently this time: using ubuntu-desktop instead of kubuntu-desktop. That leads me to the assumption that the kde wlanfrontend messed it up. But i will not check my assumption because reinstallation will take 2 hours. One drawback was still there with the broadcom wireless card: I installed the ubuntu server edition, in installation procedure i could not use the wireless card. I needed to use the server edition because only the server edition can encrypt partitions, not entire disks.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, on a netbook that uses this chipset, the additional step of setting REGDOMAIN in /etc/default/crda to my country code allows the netbook to connect to wifi APs successfully using brcmsmac, even when unhibernating.